# How to remove unused Vagrant boxes?

Tags: vagrant

`vagrant box prune` removes old versions of boxes, but I can't find any Vagrant command to remove boxes which simply are no longer in use. For example, right now `vagrant global-status` says "There are no active Vagrant environments on this computer!", but `vagrant box prune` says it's going to keep a bunch of boxes I'm no longer using. `vagrant box prune --force` doesn't do anything more.

Do I have to manually `vagrant box remove NAME` for each name?